# Need Bar Animation Gradient Fixed

Tags: animation, mesh, shaders

I have searched all over the Internet and here, but no success. I am relatively new to Blender, only used it a few months so far.

The project I'm working on is a Bar Chart. In the scene the bars are cubes with their top faces Hooked to an Empty that is animated via Python.

What I need is a way to fix the gradient position across all bars. As they grow taller, they reveal more of that gradient.

This image I made in illustrator to give you a better idea.
[image: Illustrated Bar Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try using a texture coordinate that is constant like Camera or Window -here I just did a rough try at it for illustration purposes.
[image]

Comment: Wow. That's exactly what I needed. I set it to Text. Coords. as Window and then animated the bars. The gradient stays fixed as I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution based on the world position in relation to the object. You can adjust the height by changing the denominator on the math-divide node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It makes sense, however unfortunately I can't recreate that scenario. I'm using Blender version 2.79 at work and cannot install the newer one yet.   :P

Comment: You should be able to do the same with cycles in 2.79. The nodes used are not 2.80 specific.